# Trying to upload image from app in phonegap... Getting error code 1?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm able to upload an image using the the camera, but I can't seem to get the correct file name to upload (error code 1 NOT_FOUND_ERR) when trying to upload a file from my app. What I'm trying to do is upload a default profile image to server when a user first signs up.

Here is my code, which is almost identical to the working camera upload I have:

```
// Source
path = 'images/default.jpeg';

// Destination
var url = 'http://serverloc/data';

// Upload Options
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = 'file';
    options.fileName = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = 'image/jpeg';
    options.chunkedMode = false;

var params = new Object();
params.fullpath = path;
params.name = options.fileName;

options.params = params;


// Upload
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(path, url,
    function(result) { 
        // hasn't worked yet
    },
    function(error) {
        alert('Error uploading default image: ' + error.code);
        // 1 - NOT_FOUND_ERR
    },
    options);
```

Testing on Android.

Update: Since I can't this working, I guess my next best option is to add a marker property for each user, and if that propery (default-img say) is "yes", then I'll display the default image in-app, rather than having it stored on the server.

Comment: U should give path of image (i.e your device image path) not just image/path

Comment: The image is in the "images" folder of my app, that's why I did a relative path. I also tested with an absolute path ("http://website.com/image.jpeg") and got the same error (1).

Comment: If its default y ur uploading it. Directly on the server u can control if it is a default den take the path from server itself

Comment: The way that the app services handles activities, I have to create a different asset location for each user and a copy of the default image for each user, because of the way activity posts are handled.